# Doctrine - Get row or rows from many results based on column value

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine with a one to many relationship where each user entity has many post entities. So I have a doctrine query like so

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$query = $em->createQuery(
   'SELECT u, p FROM MYUserBundle:User u
   JOIN u.post p'
);
```

I can then get the users posts like so

```
foreach($query->getResult() as $user){

   //a bunch of posts related to this user
   $posts = $user->getPosts();
}
```

For convenience I would like to create an API that will allow me to get a specific post or posts out of this $posts object based on a **column value** without using more queries. So for example I have a column named post_slug, so I would like to be able to say

```
$posts = $user->getPosts();
$post = $posts->findBySlug('my_slug');

//or something along those lines...
```

Is this something that can be done with the $posts object or Post entity class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doctrine's collections are filterable.  So, assuming your Post entities are stored on `User::$posts`, do this in your user entity.

```
public function getPostsBySlug( $slug )
{
  return $this->posts->filter( function( Post $post ) use ( $slug )
  {
    return $post->getSlug() == $slug;
  } );
}
```

Then you can just do

```
$posts = $user->getPostsBySlug( 'my_slug' );
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing

```
$slug = 'my_slug';
array_filter($user->getPosts()->all(), function ($post) use ($slug) {
    return $post->getSlug() == $slug;
})
```

Comment: this gives me Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection::all()

Answer (score 0):

You can move this kind of functionality to a Repository class (extending EntityRepository).

For example:

```
namespace Acme\ThingBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PostRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getBySlug($slug)
    {
        /// your custom query here

        return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Some info here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: He wants to only do one query, an then search with php in the fetched data.

Comment: Yes, this is not what I am looking to do. I need to run one query and then narrow things down based on column value. This can work for other relationships as well.

Comment: Oh, I see. Wouldn't the Doctrine findByPostSlug('slug_name') suffice?

Comment: Wouldn't that trigger another query?

Comment: Not if it were put in a place to replace the getPosts() call. A UserRepository class could have getPostsBySlug($slug = false), containing a query to get all the User's posts or add a where clause to only select those with a certain slug if a $slug value was passed.

Comment: As I mentioned, this can be used for other relationships as well. The idea is to query ALL results and then narrow down. Not query narrow results then do nothing.

Comment: It's probably better for you to use a filtering technique like Adrien's above. At least you'll still have access to larger set of results and you could easily make that reusable throughout your project too.